# how to get required name from a string in xslt?

Tags: xslt

e.g i have following strings:

1. xoc.coe.hw.ZSBALAJI
2. hw.cor.exp.nt.ZSSHIVA

i have to get only last string (i.e. ZSBALAJI from first and ZSSHIVA from second). How can I do it in xslt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the xml and code you have tried for this?

Comment: The answer depends very much on whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a>xoc.coe.hw.ZSBALAJI</a>
    <a>hw.cor.exp.nt.ZSSHIVA</a>
</root>
```

Then the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="//a">
        <xsl:variable name="parts" select="tokenize(node(), '\.')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count($parts)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$parts">
            <xsl:if test="position() = $count">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will ouput

```
ZSBALAJI
ZSSHIVA
```

Essentially, you can use XPath `tokenize` function and then take the last token.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an XSLT-1.0 solution to your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="//string">
        <xsl:call-template name="skipper">
            <xsl:with-param name="source" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="'.'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- returns the substring after the last delimiter -->
    <xsl:template name="skipper">
        <xsl:param name="source"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($source,$delimiter)">
                <xsl:call-template name="skipper">
                    <xsl:with-param name="source" select="substring-after($source,$delimiter)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$source"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<strings>
    <string>xoc.coe.hw.ZSBALAJI</string>
    <string>hw.cor.exp.nt.ZSSHIVA</string>
</strings>
```

It produces the following result:

```
ZSBALAJI
ZSSHIVA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use EXSLT `tokenize(string, string?)` function to split by '.' on the relevant node, see [this](http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html) for additional info.